# Create equal height two column with css

Tags: html, css, height

i want to create equal height two column, two column right will following height column left.

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

.left-side {
   background-color: green;
   height: auto;
}

.right-side-up {
    background-color: red;
    height:100px; //ignore this value, if u have other way
}

.right-side-down{
   background: blue;
   height: 80px; //ignore this value, if u have other way
}
```

[The same code on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Le24d7py/86/)

Comment: if u want to keep same height of `left-side` and `right-side` then I think you should go with `<table>` its pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks for reply, table ? do you can update on fiddle? Thanks in advance

Comment: `table(-cell)` layout is perfect when you want the shortest column to be as tall as the other one (and it could be the first or the second one). But that's not what you want, isn't it? You want the second one to have the same height  than the first one so if the second one is taller, than there'll be a vertical scrollbar. Or did I miss something? EDIT: 2nd question: which minimal version of IE do you need to support: 8, 9, 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also use some JavaScript to define equal height of left side and right side.

```js
var leftSide = document.querySelector('.left-side');
var rightSide = document.querySelector('.right-side');
var hLeftSide = leftSide.clientHeight;
var hRightSide = rightSide.clientHeight;

var maxH = Math.max(hLeftSide, hRightSide);

leftSide.style.height = maxH + 'px';
rightSide.style.height = maxH + 'px';
```

```css
.left-side {
    background-color: green;
    height: auto;
}

.right-side-up {
    background-color: red;
    height:100px;
}

.right-side-down{
    background: blue;
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
        
       
              <div class="col-xs-9 left-side">
                <p>sdfsdf</p>
                <p>sdfsdf</p>
                <p>sdfsdf</p>
                <p>sdfsdf</p>
              </div>
            <div class="row right-side">
               <div class="col-xs-3 right-side-up">
                asdfdf
               </div>
            
               <div class="col-xs-3 right-side-down">
                asdfdf
               </div>
            </div> <!-- close row -->
          
        
</div>
```

Or you can use Flexbox too

```css
.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left-side,
.right-side {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left-side {
    background-color: green;
    height: auto;
}

.right-side-up {
    background-color: red;
    height:100px;
}

.right-side-down{
    background: blue;
    height: 80px;
}

.row.no-padding,
.col-xs-3.no-padding,
.col-xs-9.no-padding {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row no-padding flexbox">
        
       
              <div class="col-xs-9 no-padding left-side">
                <p>sdfsdf</p>
                <p>sdfsdf</p>
                <p>sdfsdf</p>
                <p>sdfsdf</p>
              </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 no-padding right-side">
               <div class="col-xs-12 right-side-up">
                asdfdf
               </div>
            
               <div class="col-xs-12 right-side-down">
                asdfdf
               </div>
            </div> <!-- close row -->
          
        
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i am so sorry. i want height right-side following height left-side, i have set left-side height auto. but i stuck with right-side height, ignore height 80px and 100px.. my post any pic sample work. –

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using `jquery`

you need to use jquery and

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
     $(document).ready(function () { 
    var maxheight = Math.max($(".left-side").height(), $(".right-side").height());

    $(".right-side,.left-side").css("height", maxheight);
    });
    </script>
```

**Here is jsbin sample :**
http://jsbin.com/vobekavega/1/

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i am so sorry. i want height right-side following height left-side, i have set left-side height auto. but i stuck with right-side height, ignore height 80px and 100px.. my post any pic sample work. –

Answer (score 1):

Here what to do:

1. Remove `row` from `<div class="row right-side">` or change the name to avoid conflict
2. Then add the  3 blocks below to your css

/* The added blocks start here */

```
.right-side-up, .right-side-down {
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%; /* Adjust as needed */
}

.left-side, .right-side {
  display: inline;
    width: 50%;
}
```

/* The added Block Stops here */

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 .row {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%
}
.left-side,
.right-side {
  display: inline;
  width: 50%;
}
.left-side {
  background-color: green;
}
.right-side-up,
.right-side-down {
  width: 100%;
}
.right-side {
  background-color: orange;
}
.right-side-up {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.right-side-down {
  background: blue;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">


  <div class="left-side">
    <p>sdfsdf</p>
    <p>sdfsdf</p>
    <p>sdfsdf</p>
    <p>sdfsdf</p>
  </div>


  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="col-xs-1 right-side-up">
      asdfdf
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1 right-side-down">
      asdfdf
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- close row -->


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i am so sorry. i want height right-side following height left-side, i have set left-side height auto. but i stuck with right-side height, ignore height 80px and 100px.. my post any pic sample work. –

Comment: set the left side to always be 100%. height.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, just add a margin to the `.right-side-up`, like so:

```
.right-side-up {
    margin-top:20px; // Or margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color: red;
    height:100px;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jong561/).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but that's not what I want. i mean, height class right-side will following height class left-side, but i dont know how to make it. There left-side i use height auto. this problem only on right-side height..

Comment: How about making 1 div containing both classes?